# Wrong font on certain sites in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but not in Tor

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, fonts, tor

As you see on picture font is bad to read, and I don't know when what I did to make it.

When in Chrome through Chrome dev tools F12 in Element - Style I find font-family and change the first font that shows "Helvetica Neue" the site shows normal font again! So this "Helvetica Neue" font is bad and shouldn't show up on this site but why it is showing up and how to get rid of it?

Font Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because I had only Black version of Helvetica Neue font. After installing normal one or better deleting all Helvetica Neue fonts it shows normal font on site again.

Comment: Now I'm curious why you deleted the Helvetica fonts...but you said not to ask...I'm so torn...